# Parse three specific elements from an XML snippet in C# 2.0

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

How could parse the value of few tag from my XML using C# 2.0?

I want to parse the tag and their value like

1) `<v9:Severity>SUCCESS</v9:Severity>`

2) `<v9:TrackingNumber>634649515000016</v9:TrackingNumber>`

3) `<v9:Image>iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAyAAAASwAQAAAAAryhMIAAAagEl</v9:Image>`

How to get the value of those above elements programmatically with C# 2.0?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <env:Header xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <v9:ProcessShipmentReply xmlns:v9="http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v9">
            <v9:HighestSeverity xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">SUCCESS</v9:HighestSeverity>
            <v9:Notifications xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <v9:Severity>SUCCESS</v9:Severity>
                <v9:Source>ship</v9:Source>
                <v9:Code>0000</v9:Code>
                <v9:Message>Success</v9:Message>
                <v9:LocalizedMessage>Success</v9:LocalizedMessage>
            </v9:Notifications>
            <v9:CompletedShipmentDetail>
                <v9:CompletedPackageDetails xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                    <v9:SequenceNumber>1</v9:SequenceNumber>
                    <v9:TrackingIds>
                        <v9:TrackingIdType>GROUND</v9:TrackingIdType>
                        <v9:TrackingNumber>634649515000016</v9:TrackingNumber>
                    </v9:TrackingIds>
                    <v9:Barcodes>
                        <v9:BinaryBarcodes>
                            <v9:Type>COMMON_2D</v9:Type>
                            <v9:Value>Wyk+HjAxHTAyMDI3ODAdODQwHTEzNx02MzQ2NDk1</v9:Value>
                        </v9:BinaryBarcodes>
                        <v9:StringBarcodes>
                            <v9:Type>GROUND</v9:Type>
                            <v9:Value>9612137634649515000016</v9:Value>
                        </v9:StringBarcodes>
                    </v9:Barcodes>
                    <v9:Label>
                        <v9:Type>OUTBOUND_LABEL</v9:Type>
                        <v9:ShippingDocumentDisposition>RETURNED</v9:ShippingDocumentDisposition>
                        <v9:Resolution>200</v9:Resolution>
                        <v9:CopiesToPrint>1</v9:CopiesToPrint>
                        <v9:Parts>
                            <v9:DocumentPartSequenceNumber>1</v9:DocumentPartSequenceNumber>
                            <v9:Image>iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAyAAAASwAQAAAAAryhMIAAAagEl</v9:Image>
                        </v9:Parts>
                    </v9:Label>
                </v9:CompletedPackageDetails>
            </v9:CompletedShipmentDetail>
        </v9:ProcessShipmentReply>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Here is the LINQ to XML tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx. Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: i am working with c# 2.0 so i can't use LINQ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you said that you use c# 2.0 (and, thus, cannot use LINQ-to-XML), the easiest way to just find single values out of your XML would be to use XPath:

- You can use an XPathNavigator (MSDN: [Select XML Data using XPathNavigator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4x3f76ta%28v=VS.80%29.aspx))
- or you can use [XmlNode.SelectNodes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4bektfx9.aspx) directly.

Since your XML contains namespaces `<v9:...>`, the issue gets a bit more complicated: You need to initialize an `XmlNamespaceManager` and pass it to the `XPathNavigator`. Here is a blog post that explains this issue in detail; an example can also be found at the XmlNode.SelectNodes MSDN page (see link above).

- [Query XML with Namespaces using XPathNavigator](http://platinumdogs.wordpress.com/2009/09/02/query-xml-with-namespaces-using-xpathnavigator/)

Comment: +1. Also user should read about [xml namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950779.aspx)